# Can you use a simulacrum to bypass the 33% chance of not being able to cast wish again?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish, simulacrum

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157222/can-i-use-a-clone-to-surpass-a-wish-spell-risk) and [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/can-a-simulacrum-cast-wish), I want to know if you can cast [Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) and have that simulacrum cast [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) for you so that you yourself never have to take that 33% risk of not being able to cast it again. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/can-a-simulacrum-cast-wish) seems to support that a simulacrum is capable of casting Wish and it is a copy of the caster but at it a separate and distinct entity from the caster. So RAW can you use Simulacrum to get essentially infinite risk free wishes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RAW rules would consider the simulacrum as a separate entity, so I'd say it would work.

Adventurers League says in this [FAQ (3/24/17)](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf):

> If a *simulacrum* you have created casts *wish*, both you and your
>   *simulacrum* suffer the stress associated with casting the
>   spell—including the risk of being forever unable to cast *wish* again.
>   The inability to cast *wish* extends to any *simulacrum* you create in the
>   future.

Personally I'd houserule it to be similar to AL ruling, to prevent abuses. But if a DM is fine with this "trick" being pulled off, he might let it happen.

Comment: Can you link to the FAQ you're citing? (As far as I know, the FAQ hasn't yet been released for season 9, but [the latest one for season 8 is here](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/FAQv82.pdf#page=8), including an expanded version of that quote.)

Comment: Sure thing. Page 8: https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

### Implementing the rule that the sim's wish counts as your wish

We used the rule in [Matt DM's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/157231/26732) in our game.

In our last campaign, I played a wizard capable of *simulacrum*, who thereafter always had a sim.  We came up with some house rules to manage the spell.  For interactions with *wish*, it was essentially the same as in Matt DM's answer; however, we stated it much less formally:

- You can't use *simulacrum* to circumvent the restrictions of *wish*; your sim's wish counts as your wish.

It was, in fact, formulated after reading this question and answer.

We were both happy with this, initially.  The DM was happy I wasn't thinking I was getting permission to spam *wish*, and I was happy the DM was happy.

### But can someone use your sim to steal your wish?

However, as we gained levels from 13th toward 17th, I developed a concern.  Although more than once the sim was used as a battle tool, it was not routine; too disruptive for game flow.  Typically, the sim stayed and managed affairs at the castle while the party was adventuring<sup>1</sup>.

##### The concern

"So, wait. Eventually I'll have a sim with a 9th level spell slot.  What if while we're away, someone breaks through our defenses and somehow mind controls the sim?  Can they then cast *wish*, so that **they** get the benefits, but **I'm** the one that takes the penalty?"

It was not an idle concern.  The world was not static while we were off adventuring, such a thing could not be completely discounted.  More than once we came back to some sort of foolishness going on in the town, or outside the castle walls.

##### The DM's ruling

The DM thought about it, and then said, well, edge cases will be adjudicated as necessary, but I'll say this:

- You can't fool *wish*.  *Wish* knows who's **actually** casting it, and assigns responsibility appropriately.  *Wish* ignores shenanigans.

I was happy with that.

### Conclusion

The sim was extremely useful, and was fun to play, and we came up with a set of rules that made it work, including the two listed here.

We didn't actually ever put these specific rules **directly** to the test; I was never interested in wish spamming anyway (no matter what, it wouldn't work, it wasn't that sort of game), and no one ever tried to take control of the sim.<sup>2</sup>.  **However, these two rules helped to give us a common understanding of how things should work, and that helped make the game much more fun, so in that sense they were very successful.**

---

1 - This turned out to be more useful than we initially thought.  We had some NPCs in residence, but the DM wouldn't allow them to be decision makers.  The castle was also home to retired PCs, but again, the DM wouldn't allow them to be active participants.  We had a collection of monsters that came to live with us (which did not help our reputation with the locals), and also some bound elemental spirits, but again, not decision makers.  We did have an NPC in residence who could cast *sending*, so we had communications.  The sim managed things and never ever used a spell slot, except in a "break glass" kind of situation, which it did, once.

2 - Not that we didn't have issues.  The locals occasionally got up the courage to complain about our pet monsters.  Several times we had large numbers of undead outside the walls, so tedious to clean up (although that did help our standing with the locals, the ones that were left).  Extra-planar entities dropped by unannounced so often it got almost routine.  But no one tried to take control of the sim.